# Group by Month in SQL statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I am currently trying to do a group by select SQL statement. What I am trying to do is there is 12 months within a year. And within a month, I sum up all the outgoing items and display as a bar chart. Here is how I set up my SQL statement:

```
public List<ProductPacking> getSumProductByMonth(string prodName)
    {
        List<ProductPacking> ft = new List<ProductPacking>();

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FoodBankDB.connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Convert(INT, ddi.productQuantity)) AS totalQuantity, p.name, month(d.deliveryDate) AS deliveryMonth FROM dbo.DistributionDistributedItems ddi " +
                " INNER JOIN dbo.ProductVariants pv ON ddi.productVariant = pv.id " +
                " INNER JOIN dbo.Products p ON pv.product = p.id " +
                " INNER JOIN dbo.Distributions d ON ddi.distribution = d.id " +
                " WHERE p.name = '" + prodName + "' AND year(deliveryDate) < GETDATE() " +
                " GROUP BY p.name, month(d.deliveryDate)", connection);
            connection.Open();
            using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    DateTime deliveryMonth = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["deliveryMonth"].ToString(), "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    ft.Add(new ProductPacking(Convert.ToInt32(dr["totalQuantity"].ToString()), deliveryMonth));
                }
            }
        }
        return ft;
    }
```

In debug mode, it returns me the deliveryMonth as 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM which is not correct. I am sure that I stored the correct Date format in database. I tested the query and it returns me the correct data. Just that the date formatting got error.

I tried to format the date as January, February and so on. However, it return me an error message which is String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. I wonder why is it so because I managed to parse by year which is another of my functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `month(d.deliveryDate)` returns an `int` with the number of the month.  You cannot convert it directly to a DateTime, since it lacks the year/day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your SQL statement using [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) function to group the data by the month name:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Convert(INT, ddi.productQuantity)) AS totalQuantity, p.name, DATENAME(MONTH,d.deliveryDate) AS deliveryMonth FROM dbo.DistributionDistributedItems ddi " +
    " INNER JOIN dbo.ProductVariants pv ON ddi.productVariant = pv.id " +
    " INNER JOIN dbo.Products p ON pv.product = p.id " +
    " INNER JOIN dbo.Distributions d ON ddi.distribution = d.id " +
    " WHERE p.name = '" + prodName + "' AND year(deliveryDate) < GETDATE() " +
    " GROUP BY p.name, DATENAME(MONTH,d.deliveryDate)", connection);
```

and pass `dr["deliveryMonth"]` to the `ProductPacking` constructor:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    ft.Add(new ProductPacking(Convert.ToInt32(dr["totalQuantity"].ToString()), dr["deliveryMonth"].ToString()));
}
```

Comment: But it keep returning me January although I tested in query, there is two results which are December and January

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause looks incorrect.  Try `year(deliveryDate) < year(GETDATE())` or `deliveryDate < GETDATE()` instead of `year(deliveryDate) < GETDATE()`.

Comment: year(deliveryDate) < year(GETDATE() gives me syntax error near group by. Also in debug mode, it did return me December and January. Just that when displaying all became January

Comment: @Gwen you missed `)` in the end, it should be `year(deliveryDate) < year(GETDATE())`

Comment: It works. But it just get the record of previous years. Is there any way to display more than one year? Because I did got a December 2013 and January 2014 records by removing the year thing in where clause. But it just keep showing both January

Comment: Did you mean all of `ft` elements contain January?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I found out my mistake because at the presentation layer, I used the wrong constructor. Sorry my bad and thanks a lot